# How can I Serve an updated Json file with Expressjs?

Tags: node.js, json, express

I am storing a single array of objects in a json file. I have a worker calling an api at an interval to update the json file. The json file is being served to my site from an expressjs server. When the api is called however it serves the first version of the json file, not with the most recent data.

I saw some mention that the browser may be caching the file, however when I log the length of the array before it is served it still has the original length.

I also tried requiring the file inside the get function, thinking that might be when the file is read, however there was no change.

Here is some code:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3001
let jobData = require('/exampleFile')

app.get('/jobs', async (req, res) => {
    let data = await jobData;
    console.log(data.length)
    await res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000')
    res.set('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, private')
    return await res.send(data)}
    )

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

Comment: using require is fine, but your path is not, it should be `require('./exampleFile')`

Comment: why are you await'ing everything?

Comment: The path I was using was finding the file, just not giving new results once the file updated.

At first the file was serving empty so I threw awaits on everything and it went through.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution, while writing the question. I changed the way the file is read to use the fs module instead of using require:

```
    const jobData = await JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('/exampleFile', 'utf8'));
```

Comment: Get rid of the `await` there.  It's not doing anything useful as there are no promises involved anywhere in this line of code.  If this is a server, you should be using `fs.readFile()`, not `fs.readFileSync()`.  In more recent versions of nodejs, you could use `const jobData = JSON.parse(await fs.promises.readFile('/exampleFile', 'utf8'));` where you are using the promise version of `readFile()` and then using `await` on that promise.  `await` is ONLY useful when awaiting a promise.